# Using Threads and Tasks Concurrently in .NET. Best Practice

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, synchronization, task

I am new to multi threading and parallel computing and have been tasked with adding this functionality to a batch application at my job. I understand the basic fundamentals of using Threads and Tasks in C# to accomplish parallel programming. I need a little guidance on if it is considered best practice to use Threads and Tasks concurrently to accomplish a group of long running processes.

Specifically, I have implemented 3 threads in my application and each thread is sending 3 different requests out to a web service API and processing the results that are returned. At one time, a total of 9 requests are sent. Each request is represented by a Task in C#. I have included a simple example below to show what I am trying to accomplish in my application. Please let me know if this implementation is best practice. Thanks.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Thread thread1 = new Thread(() =>  Run());
    Thread thread2 = new Thread(() => Run());
    Thread thread3 = new Thread(() => Run());

    thread1.Start();
    thread2.Start();
    thread3.Start();

    thread1.Join();
    thread2.Join();
    thread3.Join();

    Console.ReadKey();
}

private async static void Run()
{
    Task tt1 = WebServiceProcess("Task1");
    Task tt2 = WebServiceProcess("Task2");
    Task tt3 = WebServiceProcess("Task3");

    await Task.WhenAll(tt1, tt2, tt3);
}

private async static Task WebServiceProcess(string taskName)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Task {taskName} has started.");

    for(int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
    {
        await Task.Delay(100);
        Console.WriteLine($"Task {taskName}: {i}");
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"Task {taskName} has ended.");
}
```

Comment: You should take a look at [the TPL library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library) as it does most of the hard work for you :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first rule of multi-threading is don't do multi-threading :) This is usually meant as a joke, with a hint to the pains and pitfalls that can arise when doing parallelism. That is one of the reasons the TPL (Task Parallel Library) was created, which abstracts away the handling of threads directly. Threads need a lot of management, maybe synchronization, locking, blocking, termination and so on, which the TPL abstracts away and handles for you.

My advice is to take a look at the official documentation here:
[Parallel Programming in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/) which will take you through everything you need to know.

These articles come with great examples that showcase the best practices when it comes to parallel programming on .NET.

Using raw threads, or managing your own thread pool is usually not considered a good practice unless you really have no other option.

Answer (score 2):

It is not best practice, because you are mixing explicit creation of threads and tasks. Generally when working with tasks you don't want to control threads. A `Task` may use many different threads during its lifetime, or only one thread, or [no thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html) at all. In most cases this is out of your control anyway. Your only consideration should be to protect access to shared resources, in case you have many concurrently running tasks that mutate shared variables or fields or properties.

Your example code could be modified to use exclusively tasks like this:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var task1 = Task.Run(RunAsync);
    var task2 = Task.Run(RunAsync);
    var task3 = Task.Run(RunAsync);

    await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2, task3);

    Console.ReadKey();
}

static async Task RunAsync()
{
    Task tt1 = WebServiceProcess("Task1");
    Task tt2 = WebServiceProcess("Task2");
    Task tt3 = WebServiceProcess("Task3");

    await Task.WhenAll(tt1, tt2, tt3);
}
```

Essentially 9 tasks are started together and are running concurrently, and the program awaits them all to complete before continuing with the next command (the `Console.ReadKey` line). Splitting the tasks in groups of three makes no practical difference regarding the tasks completion. It could make a difference only if you had code after `await Task.WhenAll` inside the method `RunAsync`, because this code would run when a group of three was completed, and some groups could complete faster than others.

Comment: Thank you very much for this response. So when using Tasks, there really isn't a good way to tell the CLR to run specific tasks on one processor and run the other tasks on another processor on the CPU? I was under the impression that you could control which set of tasks are assigned to a core by using Threads.

Comment: @Dwayne you may have control for some kind of tasks. The infrastructure includes the concept of [`TaskScheduler`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler) and `SynchronizationContext`, and you may use these to obtain fine control for tasks that are CPU intensive. But when you have tasks that call web services, and I/O bound tasks in general, think about it: It's not your processor that gets the job done. It is the processor of an other machine, somewhere in the globe. The active piece of hardware on your end is your network card, not your processor.